# Как прописать обработчик события click на элемент ?

Tags: события, javascript

начинаю вникать в мир javascript, естественно, по книгам (Д. Флэнаган), наткнулся на проблему при обработке события click на элементе button (native javascript). Нарисовал себе простенький примерчик: есть поле ввода input и кнопка button, по click'у на которой мне хотелось бы, чтобы текст, введенный в input добавлялся в элементом li в списочек ниже этой незамысловатой конструкции.

HTML код:

```
<body>
<div id="main_container" class="wrapper">
    <div id="input" class="inp">
        <div class="input">
            <input id="input_data" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="but">
            <button id="submit" class="sub">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <ol id="task_list">

        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

в js-файле приписываю такую функцию:

javascript код

```
var b = document.getElementById('submit');
console.log(b);

b.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("enter to click_handler"); //для проверки
    var source = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.log(source); //для проверки
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    console.log(item); //для проверки
    if (!source && !item) console.log("source leer or item doesn't create");
    item.innerHTML = source.value;
    document.getElementById('task_list').appendChild(item);
});
```

классы прописаны для привязки стилей, ну это понятно. А вот при работе обработчика - его я, кстати, написал по примеру из книги Фленагана и поискам на javascript.ru - работа не идет. В b присваивается null, хотя прописанный в консоли браузера выдает явно не null

[image: Imgur]

вот и вопрос - что же я делаю не так? о_0

Comment: в `window.addEventListener('load',function() { /*ваш код*/}` завернуто ?

Comment: нет... ой, блиин :(
да, Вы бесконечно правы - так работает, как планировалось. Правильно ли я понял, что весь js-код должен быть обёрнут таким образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@alexelev](/users/13034/alexelev), обращаться к элементам DOM имеет смысл после того как они будут загружены. Момент загрузки возникает непосредственно сразу после закрывающего тэга элемента.

Для правильной работы скрипта, обращающегося к элементам DOM вы можете разместить свой скрипт:

1. в `<head>` секции, тогда нужно его обернуть как написано у [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto), при этом буду загружены также стили, картинки и т.д., либо заменить событие `load` на событие `DOMContentLoaded`, которое возникает после загрузки всех элементов DOM, но не дожидается загрузки всего остального ([RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)).
2. непосредственно после элемента. На некоторых страницах вы можете заметить, что тэг `<script>` идет в середине страницы и в нем идет обращение к элементам dom без такого "оборачивания". все верно, элемент добавлен в DOM к нему уже можно обращаться.
3. перед закрывающим тэгом `</body>`, все элементы на странице будут загружены, также оборачивание не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Если файл прикреплен или скрипт записан в хед

```
window.onload = function(){

код

}
```

Поскольку документ еще не загружен. Не вижу смысла так усложнять.

1. Можно прописать `onclick ="add()"` уже в кнопке и не искать ее по айди
       (просто прописать ф-ю)
2. Если у элемента есть айди нет смысла обращаться через тэгнейм,
       класснейм и т.д.
3. Если уж обращаться через `getElements` нужно помнить, что вам
       возвращается массив даже если
       состоит из одного  элемента.
4. `source` это элемент и для  интерпретатора он всегда "правда" как и любой объект. Для верности проверяйте значение элемента на равенство с пустой строкой.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <style>

    </style>
<body>
<div id="main_container" class="wrapper">
    <div id="input" class="inp">
        <div class="input">
            <input id="input_data" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="but">
            <button id = "submit" class="sub">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <ol id="task_list">

        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.onclick = function()
{
    var source = document.getElementById("input_data");
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    if (source.value == ""&& !item) console.log("source leer or item doesn't create");
    item.innerHTML = source.value;
    document.getElementById('task_list').appendChild(item);

}


</script>
</html>
```